# Can I make the Everyplay Unity SDK use the native Facebook iOS login dialog?

Tags: everyplay

Is there a way to make the Everyplay modal login with Facebook to use the native login dialog?

I was thinking that maybe adding the Facebook SDK to the project will help but it didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is available with the SDK update 1.8.0 - May 14th 2014 (build 1801).